# Error from server (BadRequest): container "grafana" in pod is waiting to start: PodInitializing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grafana, kubernetes-pod

Recently worked on a deployment for `grafana` instance which I edited the replicas within the spec: block from "1" to "0" --- intention was to scale down the replicas of the deployment but did something totally different which caused things to end up in the following state:

- container "grafana" in pod "grafana-66f99d7dff-qsffd" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

Even though, I brought back the replicas to their initial state with the default value, the pod's state still stays on `PodInitializing`

Since then, I have tried the following things:

- Rolling Restart by running `kubectl rollout restart deployment [deployment_name]`
- Get logs by running `kubectl logs [pod name] -c [init_container_name]`
- Check if nodes are in healthy state by running `kubectl get nodes`
- Get some additional logs for the overall health of the cluster with `kubectl cluster-info dump`

Here is an output of the yaml for the `grafana` deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-27T11:22:44Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app: grafana
    chart: grafana-3.7.2
    heritage: Tiller
    release: grafana
  name: grafana
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "371133807"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/grafana
  uid: fd7a12a5-c8bc-11e9-8b38-42010af0015f
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
      release: grafana
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 26c545fd5de1c9c9af86777a84500c5b1ec229ecb0355ee764271e69639cfd96
        checksum/dashboards-json-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/sc-dashboard-provider-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/secret: 940f74350e2a595924ed2ce4d579942346ba465ada21acdcff4916d95f59dbe5
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: grafana
        release: grafana
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: admin-user
              name: grafana
        - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: admin-password
              name: grafana
        - name: GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: plugins
              name: grafana
        image: grafana/grafana:6.2.5
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /api/health
            port: 3000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        name: grafana
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: service
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: grafana
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/health
            port: 3000
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
          name: config
          subPath: grafana.ini
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/ldap.toml
          name: ldap
          subPath: ldap.toml
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
          name: storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - chown
        - -R
        - 472:472
        - /var/lib/grafana
        image: busybox:1.30
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: init-chown-data
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
          name: storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        runAsUser: 472
      serviceAccount: grafana
      serviceAccountName: grafana
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: grafana
        name: config
      - name: ldap
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: ldap-toml
            path: ldap.toml
          secretName: grafana
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: grafana
```

And this is the output of the yaml with `kubectl describe` for the pod

```
Name:           grafana-66f99d7dff-qsffd
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           gke-micah-prod-new-pool-f3184925-5n50/10.1.15.208
Start Time:     Tue, 16 Mar 2021 12:05:25 +0200
Labels:         app=grafana
                pod-template-hash=66f99d7dff
                release=grafana
Annotations:    checksum/config: 26c545fd5de1c9c9af86777a84500c5b1ec229ecb0355ee764271e69639cfd96
                checksum/dashboards-json-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
                checksum/sc-dashboard-provider-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
                checksum/secret: 940f74350e2a595924ed2ce4d579942346ba465ada21acdcff4916d95f59dbe5
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-03-15T18:26:31+02:00
                kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container grafana; cpu request for init container init-chown-data
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/grafana-66f99d7dff
Init Containers:
  init-chown-data:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         busybox:1.30
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      chown
      -R
      472:472
      /var/lib/grafana
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/grafana from storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from grafana-token-wmgg9 (ro)
Containers:
  grafana:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          grafana/grafana:6.2.5
    Image ID:       
    Ports:          80/TCP, 3000/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Liveness:   http-get http://:3000/api/health delay=60s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=10
    Readiness:  http-get http://:3000/api/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER:      <set to the key 'admin-user' in secret 'grafana'>      Optional: false
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'admin-password' in secret 'grafana'>  Optional: false
      GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS:          <set to the key 'plugins' of config map 'grafana'>     Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /etc/grafana/grafana.ini from config (rw,path="grafana.ini")
      /etc/grafana/ldap.toml from ldap (rw,path="ldap.toml")
      /var/lib/grafana from storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from grafana-token-wmgg9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      grafana
    Optional:  false
  ldap:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  grafana
    Optional:    false
  storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  grafana
    ReadOnly:   false
  grafana-token-wmgg9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  grafana-token-wmgg9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  FailedMount  19m (x82 over 169m)    kubelet  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "ldap" : secret "grafana" not found
  Warning  FailedMount  9m24s (x18 over 167m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[ldap], unattached volumes=[grafana-token-wmgg9 config ldap storage]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  4m50s (x32 over 163m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[ldap], unattached volumes=[storage grafana-token-wmgg9 config ldap]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

As I am still exploring and trying to research how to approach this, any advice, or even probing Qs are more than welcome to think through this.

Appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: Did you look into the warnings about not being able to mount the volume?

Comment: From what I remember the pod gets stuck in initializing state if the init pod can't finish successfully.

Comment: Hey Jabbson, 

yes looked at the warnings related to mount the volume and thought that they are not coming up as the entire container grafana is down.

Comment: You actually have a point - the init pod fails and that makes the entire setup along with the container grafana to fail. I will look at the init pod and tackle the mount volume issues to see if I can resolve it.